# How to start a command from a usercontrol to a window

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

So I am making a webbrowser. I made my own address bar usercontrol, it is in the same solution as the main window. This is what I want to happen.
I have an event called `getcurrentbrowser()` in the `MainWindowClass`,
But I need it to be called from the `Addressbar` class,
And then change the webbrowser's source in the `Addressbar` class,
And this command is launched by an image.

Comment: Well I tryed using `class name`.`Command` but it doesnt seem to work like a windows form

Comment: @Thaky Could u make it clear what do u want to achieve? As far as I could understand, you need to move the `getcurrentbrowser` to `Addressbar` class. And is `getcurrentbrowser` an event or a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a property like `Source` to `MainWindowsClass` and another to `AddressBar` Control.
Then Bind Source Property of `WebBrowser` and `AddresssBar` to `MainWindowClass.Source` Property with `Mode=TwoWay`